# Typescript, why would someone use a hardcoded value in generics, NodeJS - Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm wondering why someone would use this generic code (it's from express lib used with NodeJS):
the generic type "Method" in the code below, is not used in the interface and I think it cannot be used in the interface as well!, but it is used when declaring some datatype in other places, I'm wondering what is the benefit of using such code,
Appreciate your answers

```js
export interface IRouterMatcher<
    T,
    Method extends 'all' | 'get' | 'post' | 'put' | 'delete' | 'patch' | 'options' | 'head' = any
> {
    <
        Route extends string,
        P = RouteParameters<Route>,
        ResBody = any,
        ReqBody = any,
        ReqQuery = ParsedQs,
        Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>
    >(
        // tslint:disable-next-line no-unnecessary-generics (it's used as the default type parameter for P)
        path: Route,
        // tslint:disable-next-line no-unnecessary-generics (This generic is meant to be passed explicitly.)
        ...handlers: Array<RequestHandler<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals>>
    ): T;
```

Comment: I doubt there is a point really, maybe it's just not really cleaned up after a refactoring or something?

Comment: See this PR where it was originally added https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/42994

Comment: @captain-yossarian

In the PR they use the type "Method" in the interface, but in this case they don't use it at all.
they use it when they want to declare a function like this:

get: IRouterMatcher<this, 'get'>;     


I want to know in general in Typescript why would we use a hard-coded value when we define some generics

Thanks

Comment: There are might be different cases. You might wonna negate some argument like here https://catchts.com/type-negation or do some sort of validation like here https://catchts.com/validators . I depends