# Why will using `any` as the default type for a constrained generic type still keep the constraints?

Tags: typescript

I was intrigued [by another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69988455/typescript-why-would-someone-use-a-hardcoded-value-in-generics-nodejs-expres) which basically had this code [from the DT repo](https://github.com/andoshin11/DefinitelyTyped/blob/281f74ed1974d7fcddbaf59ca8b9dc1c51466e15/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L58):

```
interface RouterMatcher<T,_Method extends 'all' | 'get' | 'post' | 'put' | 'delete' | 'patch' | 'options' | 'head' = any> { /* various methods here */ }
```

In practice, this forces any user of this interface to only supply one of the listed literal types:

```
interface IRouter {
    get: RouterMatcher<this, 'get'>;
    post: RouterMatcher<this, 'post'>;
    put: RouterMatcher<this, 'put'>;
}
```

Adding a field `foo: RouterMatcher<this, 'foo'>;` to the above will not be allowed by the compiler and will result in

```
TS2344: Type '"foo"' does not satisfy the constraint '"all" | "get" | "post" | "put" | "delete" | "patch" | "options" | "head"'.
```

OK, so I get how most of the typing works, and I understand what a default type is (not having to supply it), but I still do not quite get how using `any` as the default in this example works, even after reading these two references:

- [The `any` type in the TS Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any)
- [List of rules for optional types in the TS Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

From the above, `any` should basically disable type checking, so I cannot see how passing on `any` would preserve the restriction that the type is a union of literal types. One of the rules state

> Default types for a type parameter must satisfy the constraint for the type parameter, if it exists.

So `any` satisfies *anything*, how can it also preserve the restriction?

A side-note: passing a default of `'all' | 'get' | 'post' | 'put' | 'delete' | 'patch' | 'options' | 'head'` seems to do exactly the same, but is of course more verbose.

[Sandbox to play with this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGcBcFcCNwFAEsB2kCmAnAZgQwMbqgBK6AjtOlADwCCANAEL0DCAfKAN64BcDosHs1D4eLAL7I0WPIRJUADgHsU4dHQ7c%20kyAE8FRAHLoAHpABi0FPkhIVoALyhL12yoR6DoWgoUAbJHxcNxRHLkkQBAQQUGxMJQBbUAALSEgFcB4QAHMkSGS4ADp8ROBcFAATJXBk1ABGOuAAEXRsVDz0P10AFX10CuBYPyVYYAAmAA467AB2ABZ%20uoBOeYqZ7HwKithcbABWJaCJ2CWK-Dr8Pbq5gDYb9Dq94E8qYFMFTCpwAFo1TAA3dC-SDBQLfEqfYCoCqmQoVQqQcAAYgAMnM6gh3kpMJBQKgMDgCEQmoEQrhMLpqN1NKAANoAa3Quh4EEgmFQ2QAuizugBuUCSLE4vHSQlyAAK5NwCXAJJsdhQ5N0XDpjOZrPZKC5LKgmuy-MFJmUwpeoElmGl4FomAtyqcuo5tM5vMxRuxuNN5stYS9MrlZIpoAAPmapTLrbaXUKPX1Q-lfeAwg6tcH5NkAKJG1MR3CU5PZVOkDNGthRt3C-EyInyChUSAACXKFT8WGo4tApgwlUTCZ9YdlpIVSvo8nAjCUFTtoHKuhHpDI48nYRnmgQoHXoBiiICaB4FSQ4FwQyBKE73x3RCCfj8R5b3xeiYAFN1aomDx2zOhKv1YvEkk2RHKAByXFOy-Cpf0SadQFNXAAlwN9QkRagxkKMY1w3R9PjIFl50oGhxTnKhF1nGsSLYEdPkyUdlFUdRSDHCddAo0BTzMFljDMFx5RUABKFkZxdSRXWNGMvDwutG0qFtMATNsPy7Coe37PsLT9QcVGHUcSOXFBSPnHSnBXDD1ycCSoCk5tW0I7SmKIhcmLYEzsxtXNqHMhsmxkts2FLKJKzFIhiCUaACQAWWCfBklbbp6AAfTC9B8gnBTwMTIC4L8IDUyA7IkuykMgOUKACtAIrQtKoCYRbDBKoUSLkkqpQFBCcBKui3AKmyoy9M0YSAtkIgAElgtCrAuGczLcJC8KGtbfIDxHDLryAvyN1APLIGmsbMAiyAovm18ls21aXXW4qtpIGasD2g7MGoBbwCWi7TuchRQu22b9ui%207Hueiq1o3bAlCUT6brm36jrK4GlFOzcwG6ABlMYAGY5jmHlYyAgAiGHseyqoqFYpRcUPWxwGwZV8kvFRdVwfEyuxzLsdTbHNpZkNsYujnQC50Keex6qkvQAX6u%20gXmtagWOoqfHCkfVH0d4hB%20tFQbQDC3RRoJCb1owKBzBBsHdohh6oeWrKcpOnKXptiqcqF2qbYapqWoVNqcplyqYdevW6wAeTdzS-GN26frNg8-OEkpVFxXAwk4cRp0TTXtawF0EFwBE60NpQgA)

Comment: ```any``` in this case is not part of the generic type, it just say if the type is not given it is any of the defined types. It does matter which of the given type are provided so to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to think about `any` as 'shortcut which disables typing', but it's not technically correct. `any` is kind of 'super type' which is everything at the same time. I.e. `any` is `"get"`, `"post"`, `string`, `number`, `MyCustomType`, all at the same time. This allows `any` to pass any type checks, including type parameter constrains. But besides it's special nature, it behaves as any other type, it doesn't have power to magically disable typecheck for function where it was mentioned, it's just special type which can pass any typecheck, but doesn't influence it's surroundings in any other way.

So returning to your example, answer is that `any` just satisfies the constraint. For TypeScript (in terms of type correctness) it's same as `RouterMatcher<this, 'post'>` and so TS has nothing to complain about.